# How to make jQuery output only one value at a time from .each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, each

I have the following jQuery conditional code which I forked from [CodePen](http://codepen.io/renvrant/pen/ogeeBY). I have extended the code to use a select field as well and everything works fine except that when I use multiple values in `data-cond-val` jQuery outputs all of the values and only the last value is executed.

For example in the code provided below, when I use `data-cond-val="no, maybe"`, only maybe value is used/executed on event change whether its used on a select option, input check or input radio.

## Here's the HTML code

```
<div id="demo">         
            <select name="" data-cond="example1">
                <option name="example1" data-cond="example1" value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option name="example1" data-cond="example1" value="no">No</option>
                <option name="example1" data-cond="example1" value="maybe">Maybe</option>
            </select>

        <div class="conditional" data-cond-opt="example1" data-cond-val="yes">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="example2" data-cond="example2"><span></span> Are you sure?</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="example3" data-cond="example3"><span></span> Really super sure?</label>
            <div class="conditional" data-cond-opt="example2" data-cond-val="on">
                Hooray!
            </div>
            <div class="conditional" data-cond-opt="example3" data-cond-val="on">
                Don't get cocky!
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="conditional" data-cond-opt="example1" data-cond-val="no, maybe">
            <p>
                That's a shame. Will you change your mind?
            </p>
            <label><input type="radio" name="example4" data-cond="example4" value="yes"><span></span> Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="example4" data-cond="example4" value="no"><span></span> No</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="example4" data-cond="example4" value="maybe"><span></span> Maybe</label>
            <div class="conditional" data-cond-opt="example4" data-cond-val="yes">
                Great!
            </div>
            <div class="conditional" data-cond-opt="example4" data-cond-val="no, maybe">
                Maybe
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     $('.conditional').conditionize();
    </script>
```

## Here's the jQuery code

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.conditionize = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            hideJS: true
        }, options );

        $.fn.showOrHide = function(listenTo, listenFor, $section) {
            //checkbox and radio input types
            if ($(listenTo + ":checked").val() == listenFor) {
                $section.slideDown();
            } 
            // select box   
            else if ($(listenTo + "option:selected").val() == listenFor) {
                $section.slideDown();
            } else {
                $section.slideUp();
            }
        }

        return this.each( function() {

            var listenTo = "[data-cond=" + $(this).data('cond-opt') + "]";

            // check if data att has multiple values
            var multiVals = $(this).data('cond-val').split(' ').join(',');          
            var len = multiVals.indexOf(',');

            // if data att has multiple values
            if ( len > 0 ) {

                // create an array from the values
                var dataVals = $(this).data('cond-val').split(' ');

                var listenFor;

                $.each(dataVals, function (i, dataVal) {
                    listenFor = dataVals[i];
                });

            } else {
                var listenFor = $(this).data('cond-val');
            }

            var $section = $(this);

            //Set up event listener
            $(listenTo).change(function() {
                $.fn.showOrHide(listenTo, listenFor, $section);
            });

            //If setting was chosen, hide everything first...
            if (settings.hideJS) {
                $(this).hide();
            }

            //Show based on current value on page load
            $.fn.showOrHide(listenTo, listenFor, $section);
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

**The Question:** How do I make jQuery to take each of the multiple values separately on each event change?

I'm not sure what am messing up in my syntax! I'll be glad if someone can help by showing me how to make it work.

Here is my CodePen forked **[DEMO - http://codepen.io/peter2015/pen/ZGoJom](http://codepen.io/peter2015/pen/ZGoJom)**

In my demo above, When you select *No* and *Maybe*, they should both output the same section, but only *Maybe* option shows the section and *No* doesn't show anything when selected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this:`var multiVals = $(this).data('cond-val').split(' ').join(',');`.

A single split should be enough `var multiVals = $(this).data('cond-val').split(',');`

Or `var multiVals = $(this).data('cond-val').replace(/ /g,'').split(',');` if you wanna get rid of spaces in the attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwjrev9v/

Comment: The purpose for using **.split** and **.join** together, is to check whether `data-cond-val` attribute has more than value so that the values can be iterated via **.each** function. If I use **.split** only, the if function doesn't work. 

Please take a look at this pen **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/peter2015/pen/ZGoJom)**